# TDO basic facts reference request

Tags: reference-request, d-modules

Hello,
where can I read about some basic properties of twisted D-Modules? I would like to know, a reference, that describes how to glue these modules together/pull them back/push them forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Twisted Differential operators](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~gaitsgde/grad_2009/BB%2520-%2520Jantzen.pdf)

Comment: Your link didn't work proper for me, however it also helped me finding Gaitsgory's page, thank you!

Comment: Also check out this master thesis of some guy. It has detailed treatment for toy examples
http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~danielch/thesis/koush.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You would probably do well with any of the resources under "D-modules" on [Gaitsgory's page](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~gaitsgde/grad_2009/).  Ginzburg's lectures are good, as is the book by Hotta, Takeuchi and Tanisaki.

Comment: I already checked out the book, there is not much about tdos, however Gaitsgory's page looks promising, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Others have posted links to a scan of the Beilinson-Bernstein paper on Dennis Gaitsgory's page.  You can find a different scan on [Joseph Bernstein's page](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~bernstei/Publication_list/Publication_list.html), where it is number 49.